# how to add like and unlike condition button on click android?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I want to like on Interest 1 and dislike on Interest 0

case R.id.floatingActionButton:

```
             if() {floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hearts));
                addToInterested(postId, 1);
            }else {
                floatingActionButton.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_fav));
                addToInterested(postId, 0);
            }
            break;
```

inside the method 
private void addToInterested(String postId, int interest) {

```
    try {
        PostLikeTask postLikeTask = new PostLikeTask(this, responseListener);
        JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
        params.put("userId", authKey);
        params.put("postId", postId);
        params.put("interest", interest);
        postLikeTask.likePost(params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

ResponseListener responseListener = new ResponseListener() {

    @Override
    public void onError(String errorMessage) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
};
```

}

Comment: what is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an global `curInterest` to save current state of Interest state.

Or check state of FloatingButton:

```
Drawable myDrawable = floatingButton.getDrawable();
if(floatingButton.getDrawable()==getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable. hearts)){
    //Liked
}
```

But, I see that `floatingButton` you change background, don't care `addToInterested` state success or error, it can be make error state when your request too fast or have an error.

Comment: I'm trying this but not working I want to like and dislike like facebook like. 
                                                                                  if(floatingActionButton.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hearts)){
                    addToInterested(postId, 1);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "like clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else  if(floatingActionButton.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_action_fav)){
                    addToInterested(postId, 0);
                }

Comment: if(floatingActionButton.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hearts)) that mean you have like so that you need unlike it. don't like it.

Comment: I mean when click on Like button when user not like post than data send to server and whenever user already like this post than onclick unlike show like facebook and other app.

Comment: if(floatingActionButton.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hearts)) => you liked => if you click you need unlike => call addToInterested(postId, 0); not addToInterested(postId, 1);

Comment: Don't forget change background at onSuccess of ResponseListener to R.drawable.ic_action_fav

Comment: I want like means red heart and unlike than white heart with call addToInterested(postId, 0); for unlike and addToInterested(postId, 1); for like

Comment: you don't understand `floatingActionButton.getDrawable() == getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.hearts)`, this state check current background in floatingactionbutton, if current button show hearts icon that mean current state is liked. what is happen if you click button have icon is hearts ?